# Как в python3 обратиться к переменной по имени, используя значение из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Если на вход функции поступает строка 'one', то в функции должно возникнуть обращение к переменной, у которой имя one. То есть имя переменной совпадает с содержимым строки. В виде кода это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
one = 'foobar'

def func(name):
    if name == 'one':
        print(_переменная_с_названием_one)

func('one')

>> 'foobar'
```

Соответственно, как реализовать "_переменная_с_названием_one"? Видел пару примеров с использованием exec() в похожей ситуации, но возможно ли это сделать без exec()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
one = 'foobar'

def func(name):
    if name == 'one':
        print(globals()['one'])

func('one')
```

Comment: просто `if name == 'one': print(one)` работает (в данном случае). А если функция вложенная (если `one` не глобальное имя), то `globals()['one']` ошибочный результат вернёт.

Comment: Станислав, добрый день. Да, этот вариант работает, спасибо. у меня как раз переменная глобальная.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ Станислава. В случае, если переменная не глобальная, можно использовать locals()

```
def func(name):
    one = 'foobar'
    if name == 'one':
        print(locals()['one']) # или print(locals()[name])

func('one')
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного еще поразмыслил над своей задачей. И решил, что ее возможно решить через словари. Так как все переменные к моменту вызова уже созданы, то выглядеть это может так:

```
one = 'foobar'
two = 'barfoo'
var = {'one': one, 'two': two}
def func(name):
    print(var[name])

>>> func('one')
foobar
>>> func('two')
barfoo
```

Comment: Но учти мутабельность