# Python - удаление переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю в цикле с довольно большими массивами данных, поэтому чтобы хоть как-то помещаться в оперативную память, хочу удалять временные переменные.

Делаю это таким вот образом:

```
try:
    del(variable)
except NameError:
    # в случае отсутствия переменной
    # просто ничего не делать
    pass
except Exception as e:
    # если поймали другое исключение
    # понять что оно значит
    print(e)
```

В приведённом выше виде всё работает, но дабы уменьшить длину кода, появилось желание запихнуть всё в одну процедуру:

```
def remove_var(variable):
    try:
        del(variable)
    except NameError:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Однако в таком виде при вызове `remove_var(variable)` в случае отсутствия переменной `variable` возникает та самая ошибка `NameError`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в python3 обратиться к переменной по имени, используя значение из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591460/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-python3-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 6):

Разбейте алгоритм на несколько функций. В каждой функции используйте локальные переменные. По завершении функции они(локальные переменные) передаются GC. После проведите профилирование кода и вызывайте gc.collect() при необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
import sys


def delete(variable):
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    if variable in frame.f_locals:
        del frame.f_locals[variable]
    if variable in frame.f_globals:
        del frame.f_globals[variable]
```

Пример:

```
a = 1
delete('a')
delete('b')
```

Но нужно отметить что в общем случае это не слишком правильный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Так ведь чтобы переменная использовалась в функции, вам нужно будет её туда явно передать. А вот эта явная передача в try у вас, судя по всему, не обёрнута.

Вам здесь вообще не нужна эта чехарда с исключениями.

Проще либо проверять существование переменной перед её удалением, либо присваивать ей None вместо удаления.

Но в любом случае без танцов с бубнами не удастся это вынести в функцию, потому что нельзя просто так взять и удалить/изменить переменную во внешней области видимости - понадобится использовать global или nonlocal (что почти никогда не является хорошим решением).

Ну и скорее всего, вы пытаетесь решать частную проблему там, где правильнее изменить общий алгоритм. Если вы больше расскажете о вашем скрипте, о том, что за данные он обрабатывает, то мы сможем сказать вам, как переписать его правильно. Но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса.